# Missing dates from pdr.get_data_yahoo

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, yahoo-finance, yfinance

I have started to analyse stock exchange data to help decide over my portfolio. I have tried quite a few functions to get raw data. Recently I am using the `pdr.get_data_yahoo` function:

from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
def read_index_tickers(tickers):
hol = pd.DataFrame()
print (len(tickers))

```
   for ticker in tickers:
       try:
           df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, end)

           df.to_csv(f'd:/5_STOCKS/data/{ticker}.csv')
           time.sleep(1)
           print (ticker)
           data = {ticker : ['daily\\us\\others\\' + ticker + '.csv']}
           entry = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
           hol = pd.concat([hol,entry],axis=1)
       except Exception as err:
           print (ticker, str(err))
   hol.to_csv(dirname)
```

When I run the function `df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, end)` for just one ticker it works fine, but in a cycle quite a few tickers data are missing lines: certain dates are missing, in some cases only one date in the complete '.csv'. Any idea?

Comment: Is `pdr` an external package? What is the definition of the `get_data_yahoo` function? Could you please update this question with enough information for a minimal, reproducible example? This allows other users the capability to reproduce your issue and provide well-founded answers.

Comment: Sorry I missed to copy it from the import section:

from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the package. From the function in your question, you only use the `df` variable to which you assign the call to `pdr.get_data_yahoo` in a call to write it to a file. As per my original comment, can you please edit your question to have a [fully complete, minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?